# If loop not working as intended for perl scrpt

Tags: scripting, perl

I'm trying to create a Perl script that automatically check for changes in a data.list every hour,  `username/project/tota/datas/data.list` is where the file is and then execute the remaining codes, which in my case, is to count the number of lines in that `data.list` and upload using CURL to online database.

```
#Look for changes every 6 hours
If (changes to data.list)
{
   count number of lines,
   upload data
}
else ( no change )
{
 do nothing
}
```

The part whereby counting lines and uploading data is done. just need to find a way to automatically search for changes in `data.list` Thanks all

### Edited new :
i got this answer from cas,

```
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);
my $filename   = 'username/project/tota/datas/data.list';

my $old_mtime  = 0;
my $old_size   = 0;
my $old_digest = '';

while(1) {  # loop forever

  my ($dev, $ino, $mode, $nlink, $uid, $gid, $rdev, $size,
      $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks) = stat($filename);

  if ($mtime != $old_mtime || $size != $old_size) {
     # slurp in entire file and get its sha256 hash
     local $/;
     open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "couldn't open $filename: $!\n";
     my $digest = sha256_hex(<$fh>);
     close($fh);

     if ($digest ne $old_digest) {

        print "change detected";

        $old_digest = $digest; 
        $old_mtime  = $mtime;
        $old_size   = $size
     }
  } else {
    print "no change detected";
  };

  sleep 3600; # sleep 1 hour between iterations of the loop
}
```

problem with this is whenever i run it, it always **start with change detected** and then it will go into no **change detected** every hour, any idea how can i change this part

Comment: Do you need to know if individual files have been added to or deleted from the directory?  or just a count of the files?   If you need to keep track of individual files, do you also want to just upload any new files, or re-upload everything?

Comment: I would suggest that you keep the previous version of `data.list` to be able to spot the changes. Than run `diff --suppress-common-lines data.list.old data.list`. There are many parameters for diff that can help you customize the output to your preferences (e.g. `--line-format`), In PERL, you can catch the output of diff and perform actions you need to.

Comment: When reacting to file changes – are you aware of inotify (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316178/watching-multiple-files-with-inotify-in-perl))?

Comment: @Hermann hi, cas's is working the same as ur exmaple ! thanks tho ! anyway i edited my question, care to check it out ?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to know **IF** a file has changed and don't need to know exactly **WHAT** has changed, the easiest way is to compare a hash of the current file against a hash of the previous file.

This can be further optimised to avoid an expensive hash computation by first comparing file timestamps and file sizes.

e.g. using SHA256 from [Digest::SHA](https://metacpan.org/release/Digest-SHA):

```perl
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);
my $filename   = 'username/project/tota/datas/data.list';

my $old_mtime  = 0;
my $old_size   = 0;
my $old_digest = '';

while(1) {  # loop forever

  my ($dev, $ino, $mode, $nlink, $uid, $gid, $rdev, $size,
      $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks) = stat($filename);

  if ($mtime != $old_mtime || $size != $old_size) {
     # slurp in entire file and get its sha256 hash
     local $/;
     open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "couldn't open $filename: $!\n";
     my $digest = sha256_hex(<$fh>);
     close($fh);

     if ($digest ne $old_digest) {
        # the file has changed. upload it
        #....your curl upload code here...

        # don't forget to update the old_* variables
        $old_digest = $digest; 
        $old_mtime  = $mtime;
        $old_size   = $size
     }
  } else {
    # either the file hasn't changed or someone evil has modified it while
    # making sure the file size and mtime remains the same.
    # you'd need something like Digest::SHA to detect that :-)
  };

  sleep 3600; # sleep 1 hour between iterations of the loop
}
```

You can install `Digest::SHA` from CPAN, or it's probably already packaged for your distro.  On Debian, it's in the `libdigest-sha-perl` package.

---

I'm not sure why you even need or want to do this in perl.  If all you want to do is check if a file has changed every hour, then you'd be better off just running a simple shell script like the following from cron:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# run this as "/path/to/script-name.sh /path/to/data.list"

filename="$1"

checksumfile='/var/tmp/data.list.sha256'

# cd to the directory containing data.list
cd "$(dirname "$filename")"

if [ ! -e "$checksumfile" ] || ! sha256sum --quiet -c "$checksumfile" ; then
  # upload your file with curl
  # ... your curl code here ...
  
  # generate sha256 checksum file
  sha256sum "$(basename "$filename")" > "$checksumfile"

  # make sure it's RW by everyone
  chmod a+rw "$checksumfile"
fi
```

Comment: not files, its the data.list , i want to see if there are more data added into that list every hour

Comment: in that case, you can probably just use the file's timestamp and not bother with counting the lines.   Do you need to upload the entire file again or just the changes?

Comment: upload the entire data.list file again, im new at this , so im not sure how to do

Comment: 1. ask the sysadmins to install it for you.  2. if it's a personal script that's only going to be run by you, then install it into your home directory with `cpan Digest::SHA`

Comment: cool buddy ! thanks for the help ! much appreciated, i am going to type out now on my linux and tty

Comment: BTW, in many cases, just testing the file's timestamp and size is good enough - using a digest algorithm is overkill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126494/discussion-between-helpmeandroidstudio-and-cas).

Comment: any reason why whenever i run this , it says its not the same as previous

Comment: It would be easier to just run `rsync` every hour, regardless of what changes have been made. Or use `rsync` to detect changes between the "live" files and the state at last `curl` upload.

Comment: @Kusalananda care to elaborate more with codeS?

Comment: @HelpMeAndroidStudio No, sorry. I was just thinking aloud for myself that there already are software that does this kind of thing and wouldn't it be nice to make use of that? I have no actual code to show and not the time to implement something around `rsync` at this moment. If it wasn't for the fact that you need to upload stuff with `curl`, using `rsync` directly would be trivial.

Comment: @Kusalananda now i met this problem , problem with this is whenever i run it, it always start with change detected and then it will go into no change detected every hour, any idea how can i change this part